# metron installation over ambari-managed cluster failed

Tags: hadoop, centos, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am using centos6.5 in which successfully deployed ambari-server2.4 with 3 nodes where hadoop,yarn,strom are successfully running.

I am using this url as reference for metron installation:

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/60805/deploying-a-fresh-metron-cluster-using-ambari-serv.html

I am getting stuck when i try to install metron in ambari-server, adding metron in ambari-repository list is succeed but when installing metron nodes and elasticsearch over target node i get below exception:
**Ambari-server Console error:**

```
2017-05-25 16:33:01,138 - Installing package elasticsearch-2.3.3 ('/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install elasticsearch-2.3.3')
2017-05-25 16:33:02,132 - Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install elasticsearch-2.3.3' returned 1. Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: METRON-0.4.0. Please verify its path and try again
2017-05-25 16:33:02,132 - Failed to install package elasticsearch-2.3.3. Executing '/usr/bin/yum clean metadata'
2017-05-25 16:33:02,497 - Retrying to install package elasticsearch-2.3.3 after 30 seconds

Command failed after 1 tries
```

**Terminal error:**

```
file:///localrepo/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///localrepo/repodata/repomd.xml
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: METRON-0.4.0. Please verify its path and try again
```

Comment: This might be helpful for you https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/METRON/Metron+Installation+on+an+Ambari-Managed+Cluster

Comment: I have been go through that url too, but still not succeed. I have updated terminal error too.

Comment: try 1.`yum clean all`,2. `yum check` 3. `yum upgrade` and then you follow again

Comment: Sir i have tried these all but when again going to install metron package it create the same repo and search for metron-0.4.0